# Python : Is there a way to get the names of last three Month Names?

Tags: python, datetime

How can I extract last three month names in Python? If I am running this today then I would like to see May, June and July as my result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to do this is a combination of the `date` and `calendar` modules.

- `date.today().month` will give you a numerical value for the current month (1-12)
- `calendar.month_name[x]` will give you the name for the month represented by the number `x`
- the `%` operator will be used to wrap around the index of the `month_name` object to avoid the pesky `0` index returning `''`

Putting them together we have:

```
from datetime import date
from calendar import month_name

def previous_n_months(n):
  current_month_idx = date.today().month - 1 # Value is now (0-11)
  for i in range(1, n+1):
    # The mod operator will wrap the negative index back to the positive one
    previous_month_idx = (current_month_idx - i) % 12 #(0-11 scale)
    m = int(previous_month_idx + 1)
    print(month_name[m])
```

Example usage:

```
>>> previous_n_months(3)
July
June
May
```

Comment: Hi Chad, Based on what you said, do you see an issue with the below pasted code? import datetime as dt
import calendar as cal
def previous_month_list(no_of_months):
    current_month = dt.date.today().month
    list_of_months = [cal.month_name[x] for x in reversed(range((current_month-no_of_months),current_month))]
    print(list_of_months)

Comment: You run into a potential problem when you're doing the subtraction because `cal.month_name[0]` is `''`, so you have to handle the edge cases when you're in January, February, or March.

Answer (score 2):

- One way is to use the python [`calendar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html) module, and list slice a month name for a given, extracted datetime month.

  - [`.month_name`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.month_name) returns a list of all the month names.
  - `calendar` is part of the standard library.
- For [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#available-types), there isn't a `month` parameter because the length of a month is not a constant value, so use `days`, as an approximation.
- See [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#module-datetime) for the available methods.

  - `datetime` is part of the python standard library, so doesn't require a separate installation.
  - Use [`.month`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.month) to extract the month from the datetime.

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import calendar

# get the time now
now = datetime.now()

# iterate through 3 different timedeltas as an example
for x in range(1, 4):
    new = now - timedelta(days=31*x)
    print(calendar.month_name[new.month])

[out]:
July
June
May
```

- As mentioned in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63441494) by [bigbounty](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6849682/bigbounty), using `.strftime` with `'%B'` is a better option than using `calendar`
- However, unlike the [`dateutil`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) module, `timedelta` still doesn't have a `month` parameter.

  - *The `dateutil` module provides powerful extensions to the standard `datetime` module* and must be installed, and then imported.

```py
# get the time now
now = datetime.now()

# iterate through 3 different timedeltas as an example
for x in range(1, 4):
    new = now - timedelta(days=31*x)
    print(new.strftime('%B'))

[out]:
July
June
May
```

Answer (score 2):

Easier way is to use "%B" using datetime and timedelta

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

from datetime import datetime

today = datetime.now()

for i in range(1,4):
    print((today - relativedelta(months=i)).strftime('%B'))
```

Output:

```
July
June
May
```